# Scroll script blocked by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've got problem with scroll script for menu on my github page. Each browser constantly block js script due to pop-up window. Everything works like a charm on localhost and mobile devices like tablet or smartphone

There's code and i am wondering how to fix that issue cuz its just nav scroll script with anchors and i have no idea why whole browsers are recognizing it as pop-up window

```
$(function() {
    $('#sidenav a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        simpleScrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 500);
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var ds = $(document).scrollTop();

        if (ds == 0) {
            $('#sidenav a').removeClass('active');
            $('#sidenav a[href=#' + $('.anchor').eq(0).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');

            return false;
        }

        $('.anchor').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this), offset = Math.round($this.offset().top), height = $this.outerHeight() + offset;

            if (offset <= ds && height > ds) {
                $('#sidenav a').removeClass('active');
                $('#sidenav a[href=#' + $this.attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');
                if (document.location.hash != '#' + $this.attr('id')) {
                    var cds = $(document).scrollTop();
                    document.location.hash = $this.attr('id');
                    $(document).scrollTop(cds);
                }

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });

        return true;
    });

    var ds = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (ds == 0) {
        $('#sidenav a').removeClass('active');
        $('#sidenav a[href=#' + $('.anchor').eq(0).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('.anchor').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this), offset = Math.round($this.offset().top), height = $this.outerHeight() + offset;

            if (offset <= ds && height > ds) {
                $('#sidenav a').removeClass('active');
                $('#sidenav a[href=#' + $this.attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
        if (document.location.hash != '') {
        var el = $(document.location.hash);
        if (el.length > 0) {
            $(window).scrollTop(0);
            $(window).load(function() {
                simpleScrollTo('#' + el.attr('id'), 1000);
            });
        }
    }
});

function simpleScrollTo(element, speed) {
    $('html:not(:animated), body:not(:animated)').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top}, speed, function() {
        document.location.hash = $(element).attr('id');
    });
}
```

I've forgotten to mention. My github page is shown as "unsafe". When i allow to use unsafe script then it works. Is it caused by Github security restriction?

Comment: I'd just like to point out a (possible) typo at line 12 `$('#sidenav a[href=#' + $('.anchor'a).eq(0).attr('id') + ']').addClass('active');` you have a random a in `$('.anchor'a).`

Comment: Honestly i have no idea what "a" was doing there. I dont have it in my document so its just my mistake. Fixed it, sorry. The issue still exists

Answer (score 0):

Solved, hadn't noticed there was "http" link for jquery instead of "https" :)